# How to effectively count different clicks from same person

Tags: cookies, ip, unique

We are driving an investigation to see how possible is to get an approximate count of different visitors that click a link that redirects to another page (through an url shortener).

Right now, two typical approaches are used to distinguish different clicks from different visitors and count "unique" visitors: using Cookies and/or using IP.

Both of them are not perfect, and people can hack it (deleting cookies and/or changing IP in mobile networks, for example), and have disadvantages (people with same IP)

Ignoring what HTTP technologicaly allows (cookie / IP), We are looking for other creative ways of trying people not to hack it.

For example, google, for the Adsense program, has a "propietary algorithm" to do that. What is it based on? Does it exist an open-source algorithm that does it?

Example of ideas we are looking for:

- RIPE database is working in a prototype for the RIPE Database to have a "geoloc" field so operators set that field (more specific, mobile operators). So you will be able to know which IP is where. You can use that info to try to limit a user when has a new IP from a mobile network. - https://labs.ripe.net/Members/denis/geolocation-prototype-for-ripe-database
- Use some kind of browser fingerprint - https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Regards

Comment: Adsense uses an algorithm to track fake / automated clicks AFTER they have been done (ie: using statistical algorithms, avg ratios). The only way to track it is by IP or Cookies.

Comment: @jorgebg that would work also, what kind of algorithms are they based on? how to implement them?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Google analytics in your website, you can use event tracking feature: http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Comment: Nop, as I said it is and url shortener system, and so, it only is a page that sends a 301 redirection :) something like bit.ly

Comment: OK. Maybe you should avoid refer to clicks in the question... :)